# Do we need a Storyboard ID in iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am setting up a basic iOS app and saw the Storyboard ID section of the Identity Inspector (as well as the Use Storyboard ID checkbox) and was curious as to whether this is actually something I need to create an app. If so what do I need to set this field to given the use below:

More specifically I am setting up 2 simple views and 2 corresponding viewcontrollers in my app. I was just trying to create a simple button to go from the first view to the second view and was using this method for the button which would ultimately transition from the first view to the second view once it was pressed:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerID") as! TransitionViewController
```

The view controller for the second view I want to be the destination of the button is named TransitionViewController. I borrowed this code from some samples and "SecondViewControllerID" is the name of the storyboard from the sample I'm borrowing from. In my Xcode, the Storyboard ID field is blank at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the storyboard id to `SecondViewControllerID` or ctrl-drag from the button to the destination vc through segue

Explanation :

Storyboard identifier is a unique key set for a vc inside storyboard to identify it when you load with `instantiateInitialViewController`

Regarding segue : CTrl-drag from the button to destination and from the popup select show

[image]

and don't write any code inside button action

Answer (score 1):

The storyboard id ia mainly used when you have more than one StoryBorad.
if you have 2 storyborads you can initialize the vc by using

```
var vc = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle:nil).instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerID") as! TransitionViewController
```

and give "SecondViewControllerID" in Storyboard ID section of the TransitionViewController Identity Inspector.